# Deserialization with options

Tags: c#, deserialization

I am currently achieving serialization of a collection to the file. The results are like how I expect

```
<Persons>
  <Person>
    <Identity>1234</Identity>
    <Name>asd</Name>
  </Person>
  <Person>
    <Identity>12345</Identity>
    <Name>asdd</Name>
  </Person>
</Persons>
```

Now, I don't want to deserialize the whole collection but I want to deserialize an object from the file with some specific options. For example,

```
object GetPersonWithIdentity(int identity )
{
  // what to do here
}

object asd = GetPersonWithIdentity(1234); 
// expected Person with Identity "1234" and Name "asd"
```

Is it be reasonable to deserialize whole collection and find the specific object and return it, or is there any other solution for this?

Comment: Why exactly do you want to do that? Have you measured that deserializing the whole collection is too slow?

Comment: Of course, deserializing the whole collection will be slow for my case. But I had no answer instead of deserialization. I think it will be harder to implement XmlReader but will be much more effective

Answer (score 2):

XML is not seekable so you at least have to read forward till you find the first match. The framework does not support that automatically so you have to do it manually using an `XmlReader` which is laborious.

If the file is small and/or performance is not an issue, just deserialize everything and be done with it.

If your dataset is big I'd consider moving to some more scalable format like an embedded SQL database. SQL databases have this capability inherently.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. By the nature of project, SQL databases should not be used. If I understand it correctly, you are telling that I should use reading from file with XmlReader not deserialization?

Comment: @MehmetAliSert please elaborate on your requirements, on your data, what you want to accomplish. This does not seem like a good idea because even when not deserializing everything you only save half of the time spent on average. Does not help a lot.

Comment: @MehmetAliSert usr specifically mentioned embedded databases, which don't require a separate SQL server. Examples are SQLite or SQL Server Compact. Even those are not usable for you?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to serialize the entire XML file because as usr mentioned, XML is forward only.  XmlReader/Writer is essentially a TextReader (Stream) object, and is doing file i/o to read an XML file.

The reason for my seperate answer is I would do the following using an XDocument object:

```
object GetPersonWithIdentity(int identity )
{
  return myXDocumentVaraible.Descendants("Person")
                     .First(person => person.Element("Identity").Value == identity.ToString());
}
```